# How to create a string resource programatically

Tags: android, android-resources, webtrends

I am using WebTrends analytics in my app.
(Ref-http://help.webtrends.com/en/android/)

The WebTrends APIs are written in such a way that the initialization happens **ONLY** from resources file. They provide **`webtrends.xml`** with the sdk and all the parameters are set from the values from this xml file.

Now the problem is I have to set a couple of values dynamically based on our server feed.

Here I have only two choices:

(1) Set WebTrends initialization values in the code which looks impossible from WebTrends SDK. Neither the member variables are exposed outside the library nor there are any setters/methods to set the initialization params.

(2) Create resources from **`webtrends.xml`** dynamically or at least set the values for resources dynamically which also seems impossible.

Can anyone please suggest the way out of this deadlock?

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot do that**. When you add a string resource an automatic entry is made for the resource in R.java file at compile time.

**Example:**

```
public static final class string
{
    public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
}
```

where app_name is the name of the string resource. So, it is not possible.

Comment: it won't be converted into R.java. When you add a resource an automatic entry is made for the resource example  public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;} where app_name is the name of the string resource